# Qpython uknown RPC error

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, qpython

I installed the QPython app on Android and executed a script name **helloworld.py**. It used androidhelper's method **maketoast** to show a message with the Android api.

I tried writing the exact same script on another file but it is giving me the following error:

> com.googlecode.android_scripting.rpc.RpcError: Unknown RPC.

Then I tried to modify **helloworld.py** and it's now giving me the above error.

I searched all over the internet for this error but no solutions.

By the way, I use a rooted Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 LITE T110N.

I already tried using the **android** module, but it doesn't exist. So does **sl4a** doesn't exist.

I use python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

```
import androidhelper
droid=androidhelper.Android()
droid.makeToast("Hello, sl4a!")
#not maketoast
#it's makeToast!
#read this:
#http://www.mithril.com.au/android/doc/index.html
#when you call sl4a,you have to tell sl4a what to do, if sl4a can't recognize it,
#sl4a throws an Unknown RPC error
#Thanks
```